# Extract sub-arrays from numpy-array and get desired 3D-shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

Given an array:

```
array([[[1], [2], [3]],
       [[4], [5], [6]],
       [[7], [8], [9]]])
```

I want to create three new arrays (`encode`, `decode_in` and `decode_out`).

The `encode` array should look like:

```
array([array([[1]]),
       array([[1], [2]]),
       array([[4]]),
       array([[4], [5]]),
       array([[7]]),
       array([[7], [8]])])
```

The `decode_in` array should be the *inverse* of `encode` with an added zero to each row so the array is the same shape as the `decode_out` below, i.e.:

```
array([array([[2], [3], [0]]),
       array([[3], [0]]),
       array([[5], [6], [0]]),
       array([[6], [0]]),
       array([[8], [9], [0]]),
       array([[9], [0]])])
```

The `decode_out` should be `decode_in` but shifted one step. At the moment I solve this by prepending a zero instead of appending, as is done above.

```
array([array([[0], [2], [3]]),
       array([[0], [3]]),
       array([[0], [5], [6]]),
       array([[0], [6]]),
       array([[0], [8], [9]]),
       array([[0], [9]])])
```

---

The following code does the trick:

```
def convert_to_encodings_and_decodings(training_data):                                                                                                       

  encode = list()                                                                                                                                          
  decode_in = list()                                                                                                                                       
  decode_out = list()                                                                                                                                      

  for i in range(training_data.shape[0]):                                                                                                                  
      for j in range(training_data.shape[1]-1):                                                                                                            
          encode.append(training_data[i, :j+1])                                                                                                            
          d_in = np.concatenate((training_data[i, j+1:], np.zeros((1, 1))))                                                                                
          d_out = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1, 1)), training_data[i, j+1:]))                                                                               
          decode_in.append(d_in)                                                                                                                           
          decode_out.append(d_out)                                                                                                                         

  encode = np.asarray(encode)                                                                                                                              
  decode_in = np.asarray(decode_in)                                                                                                                        
  decode_out = np.asarray(decode_out)                                                                                                                      

  return encode, decode_in, decode_out
```

But the resulting arrays have shapes: `(119920,)`, which is incompatible with my model (written in Keras) which expects a 3D-input. (`nb_samples`, `nb_timesteps`, `nb_features`). I would expect that the final solution would output arrays of shape: `(119920, max_sub_list_length, 1)`, which is not ideal since I want to avoid unnecessary padding -- but if that's what it takes - so be it.

I have attempted to base my solution on numpy arrays instead (i.e. `encode = np.zeros(desired shape)`) and I have attempted to pad the data using:

```
  def pad_data(data, pad_to_length):

      padded_data = list()                                                                                                                                   

      for d in data:                                                                                                                                     
          pd = np.pad(route, ((0, pad_to_length - route.shape[0]), (0, 0)), "constant")                                                              
          padded_data.append(pd)                                                                                                                   

      return np.asarray(padded_data)
```

But this causes a MemoryError

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an array of arrays with different lengths, it's impossible to have a shape that fits your model with that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least two different arrays. You can't have a shape if you have different lenghts inside a single array.

```
length1 = 1
length2 = 2

originalShape = originalArray.shape
arrayWithZeros = np.zeros((shape[0], shape[1]+1, shape[2]))
arrayWithZeros[:, :shape[1], :] = originalArray    


encode1 = orignalArray[:,:length1,:]
encode2 = originalArray[:,:length2,:]

decode_in1 = originalArray[:,length1:,:]
decode_in2 = originalArray[:,length2:,:]

decode_out1 = np.zeros(decode_in1.shape)
decode_out2 = np.zeros(decode_in2.shape)
decode_out1[:,1:,:] = decode_in1[:,:-1,:]
decode_out2[:,1:,:] = decode_in2[:,:-1,:]
```

Using two different arrays like this will require that your model's length be `None`, as in `input_shape=(None,1)`.